# What are the 2-adic numbers beginning $\overline{10}$ and no consecutive two numbers permissible?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

> What are the 2-adic numbers beginning $\overline{10}$ and no consecutive two numbers permissible?

i.e.:

$\overline{10}$

$\overline{10}1$

$\overline{10}11$
etc.

But if we allow $\overline{10}11$ then $\overline{10}10$ is not permitted.

I expect there to be two mutually exclusive sets although I may be mistaken.

As for where I've got to with this problem... I really have no idea how some rule governing the repeating part to the left affects the set of numbers possible.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your notation. Could you explain? And while you’re at it, could you check the wording of your first sentence? It doesn’t look well-formed to me. Did you, perhaps, mean “Why are the…” ?

Comment: @Lubin i'm sure the apology should be mine. The wording is as intended. Overline means repeat to the left So these are separated by ascending powers of $4$ and I mean there are two rules defining a set. Firstly every number in the set has ascending powers of $4$ secondly there are no two numbers $x,y$ in the set satisfying $x+1= y$.

Comment: @Lubin P.s. If I've formulated it correctly i think this question is related to what you said about the limit of $3^n$ in the 2 adics. I intend it to discriminate two sets of numbers, one of which is associated with the powers of 4 by some bijection and the other associated with the powers of 2 by the same bijection, although I am peering a long way into the void when I say that and may be completely wrong.

Comment: Where I say every number has ascending powers of 4 I should more precisely have said every number contains a sum to infinity of $4^n$

Comment: Well, the repeating part is $\sum_{i=1}^\infty4^i$, equal to $-4/3$ if nothing appears to the right. Your second example is $1+2\cdot(-4/3)$. I guess you have to understand what the nonrepeating parts (at the right end) look like generally.

Comment: @Lubin I guess these are all thirds i.e. $\lvert x\rvert_3=3$ and we have $+2/3$ or $+1/3$ mod 1 so to speak depending whether the $\overline{10}$ is in an even or an odd parity. So I guess we WOULD have either all odd or all even numbers, extended by the addition of $\overline{10}$ or $\overline{01}$ however because $10$ is even and $01$ is odd **I think** means that in each of the two possible sets we have a mix of half even and half odd integers added to the fractional part, depending on the parity of the fractional part.